# C: nanosleep() and usleep() fails

Tags: c, xcode, multithreading, pthreads

Why my implementation of `nanosleep()` fails? I am using Xcode on my Mac, and the error is:
`Thread 2: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

```
void msleep3(int msec)
{
    struct timespec interval;
    struct timespec remainder;

    interval.tv_sec = msec / 1000;
    interval.tv_nsec = (msec % 1000) * (1000 * 1000);

    if (nanosleep(&interval, &remainder) == -1) {
        if (errno == EINTR) {
            printf("nanosleep interrupted\n");
            printf("Remaining secs: %ld", remainder.tv_sec);
            printf("Remaining nsecs: %ld", remainder.tv_nsec);
        } 

        else if (errno == EINVAL)
            printf("errno == EINVAL\n");

        else {
            perror("nanosleep");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}
```

The error is located in the line where `nanosleep()` returns, and this error isn't caught by any if/if else/else. In my program, there are 2 threads. When the problem occurs, thread 1 is on `sleep()` function, and thread 2 generates the error when it call `nanosleep()`.

**EDIT1:** The problem does not always occur, but when I launch the program I have to wait several seconds or minutes for the crash.

**EDIT2:** Xcode gives me this problem on the process view about thread 2:
`_os_lock_corruption_abort`. If I click on this, I have:
`libsystem_platform.dylib _os_lock_corruption_abort:
->  0x7fff8da21caf <+0>: ud2`

Comment: Are you building with `-pthread` ?

Comment: I am using xCode, so yes, it builds with `-pthread`

Comment: The code looks OK - I'm guessing the bug lies elsewhere - can you put together an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that others can try to reproduce this and investigate further ?

Comment: I've tried to recreate the problem in a smaller file .c, but i cannot replicate it! My program is long, so i cannot put it in a post. Can you advise me some proof that I can do to create an MCVE? Anyway, my program is a multithread program, and i use `pthread_mutex` for critical sections.

Comment: You may be doing something non-thread-safe in your code somewhere, either explicitly or perhaps by calling a non-reentrant library function. This is the down-side of using multi-threading - debugging can be a lot tougher than with single-threaded programs. Anyway, good luck, and if you do ever manage to create an MCVE then post that to see if anyone else can help.

Comment: This smells like massive memory (management) corruption.

Comment: @alk How can i investigate about this?

Comment: You might like to use memory checker like Valgrind (https://valgrind.org) on this. Which is a good idea in any case, btw.

Comment: Ok, i'll try with Valgrind. Thanks